# how can i change the pseudo class (:after and :before) style dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, pseudo-element

Please note I don't have a standard set of colors, instead, the colors will come from the color picker

I want to change the background and the color of the pseudo-class element that was passed in class. and both are a different color, I tried the concept of `currentColor` of the parent, but that applies to even the content and background.

Is there a way to dynamically change these color?

Comment: Can you share some code how your elements looks like?

Comment: If you have a limited number of colour options, you could do it by applying classes corresponding to those colours to the containers. If not (or if there are too many options to create classes for them all) then you could look at writing the styles to an inline style block.

Comment: thanks @de but this is age old , i need something dynamic.

Comment: @MayankPatel   let me try to give some code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wza23251/ something of this kind

Comment: If you are applying the color to the parent element, you can try using color:inherit, to adjust font and border color.  Elsewise, your example needs to be more clear and specific.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this blog as it helped me some time ago in dynamically changing the pseudo class's color. http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css . Hopefully it will help.

Comment: this dint help , i had to pass the color dynamically to the element and use the property "currentColor" in cszs to reflect the dynamic color, only problem here we faced was in active state of the step , so we decided we will be changin the look and feel of the active state. Hope this helps for anyone. thanks!

Comment: ur example  http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css 
 again has explicit coloring , i want it when the color is dynamic from a form or api value.

Comment: i thought this would work. would look again into this.